# How to send an email on behalf of user

Tags: email, spam, zimbra

I have two zimbra mail servers, on server-1 I have one domain with accounts. I want to be allowed to send email from server2, on behalf of account@domain.com that I dont have on server2, but this domain *@domain.com I have on server1. For now I can send such email on behalf of user that I want, but I can receive only in spam folder. What record should I add and where, so this can be done without going to spam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons why email could end up in someone's spam folder. In your case, however, the first thing I would look into is correctly setting up the **SPF records**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework):

> SPF allows the receiving mail server to check during mail delivery that a mail claiming to come from a specific domain is submitted by an IP address authorized by that domain's administrators.[3] The list of authorized sending hosts and IP addresses for a domain is published in the DNS records for that domain.

In other words, you will need to create a DNS record for your domain that explicitly authorizes `server2` to send email on behalf of that domain. More information specifically for Zimbra can be found on [the Zimbra Wiki](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Best_Practices_on_Email_Protection:_SPF,_DKIM_and_DMARC)

Comment: Thanks very much, this is answer of my question. After I "whitelisted" IP address in SPF on my domain name record, now emails not going to spam.